# Some "expandable" variables not expand

Tags: windows, environment-variables

Rapid Environmet Editor proposes an option to edit "expandable" environment variables.

Apparently, this is the feature of Windows.

Unfortunately, some of variables not expand.

I made a group of assignments:

[image]

blue icons mean "expandable", but some of variables are not expand:

[image]

I can't figure out a law, by which it happens.

May be it can't expand nested expandings?